# How to add data in json response?

Tags: python, json, metadata

I want to add data in my json response from request.post in python.

**From this.**

```
{
  "key" : "value"
}
```

**To this ...**

```
{
  "key" : "value"
  "metadata" : { "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*. You have shown what you want to do. What is the *difficulty* in doing this? Did you try to write the code to do this? What happened when you tried using your code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it very easily:

```
data = response.json()
data["metadata"] = yourData
```

Comment: I tried printing (response.text) and the metadata wont add app. What will i do?

Comment: r=request.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data); r = r.json(); r["metadata"] = yourData

Comment: It says dict object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: ya, if you want check metadata, you should print r["metadata"] instead of r.text. 

r=request.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data); r = r.json(); r["metadata"] = yourData; print(r["metadata"])

Answer (score 0):

You can add key and value as following

```
data = {
  "key" : "value"
}
data["metadata"] = { "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"}
```

Comment: "I have r=request.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)" It would help if you show that code in the original post, and try to be clear about what you are doing. Did you just get some data, and want to modify the data you received? Or are you trying to modify the `json=data` that you will use to *make* the request? Or just what?